# Saving Image in a seperate directory in android

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I can rake pictures from this code but i am not able to save the pictures into custom directory          `Uri uriTarget = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());`
and i think this is probably the line where i have to change my code 
want to make a custom directory and save my image there

```
Camera.ShutterCallback myShutterCallback = new Camera.ShutterCallback(){



        @Override
        public void onShutter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }};

    Camera.PictureCallback myPictureCallback_RAW = new Camera.PictureCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }};

    Camera.PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new Camera.PictureCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            Uri uriTarget = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());


            OutputStream imageFileOS;

            try {

                imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriTarget);

                imageFileOS.write(arg0);

                imageFileOS.flush();

                imageFileOS.close();



                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,

                        "waH kiAa selfie hAi :D ",
                        //+ uriTarget.toString(),

                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            camera.startPreview();
        }};
```

Comment: Do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in your manifest-file ?

Comment: yes sure i have the above code which i have mentioned is saving picture in camera default directory But i want to save it in custom directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach...

```
        private void saveImage(byte[] arg0) {
            String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "YOUR_CUSTOM_FOLDER";
            File myDir = new File(root);
            myDir.mkdirs();
            String fname = "YOUR_IMAGE_NAME" + ".jpg";
            file = new File(myDir, fname);
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
            }

            Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length);
            FileOutputStream out;
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(activity.getContentResolver(), bitmap1, "", "");
        }
```

Comment: Where ur planning to save the image, there u should paste the code.

Comment: @Brendom, your statement is contradictory statement, your saying not working..and your saying where to put the code...either you haven't tried nor you don't know where to add code?

Comment: I have put that code in mypicturecallback but it's not working can you please tel me where to put it ???

Comment: First check whether the callback is triggering or not, then just call this method in the callback

Comment: You could put the function `saveImage()` anywhere in the source file but NOT in `onPictureTaken()`. In onPictureTaken you only have to call it with `saveImage(arg0);`. `

Comment: In gallery, you can see as folders but in Photos go to navigation drawer icons and select on device..you can see the folders too

Comment: `how to make that folder visible in gallery`. Then you have to invoke the mediascanner on your new file. Or switch your device off/on. Google for code. It's only one code line.

Comment: @HarshaVardhan why the picture is getting save in multiple directory as one custom directory and other the camera default the picure is getting save in both directories ??